# How to output the data in a database table every 2 seconds?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have database table named LETTER and has a column of LETTER. It has a data of alphabets starting from A until Z. I want it to output in order every 2 seconds and if it's at the end of the file, it'll loop back to A. My program outputs all of the letters all at once from A-Z. Then, it outputs another random letters and also all at once. I want it to output one at a time and in order. How can i fix it?

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class GUIThread {
    static Connection con; 
    static Statement stmt; 
    static ResultSet rs;
    int curRow = 0;

    public static void DoConnect(){
        try{
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Mariel";
            String uName = "mariel";
            String uPass = "1234";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM LETTER";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            while(rs.next()){
                final String letter;
                letter = rs.getString("LETTER");
                class SayHello extends TimerTask {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(letter);
                    }
                }
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 2000);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DoConnect();
    }
}
```

This is the output of my program and i dont want it to be that way: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5XVI.png)

Comment: You could put all the letters in a `List` and then use the `Timer` as a pseudo loop to loop over the `List`

Comment: @MadProgrammer alright, i'll try that when i got home

Comment: I use C#, not Java, but surely creating a class definition in a while loop must be a horrible practice with intense overhead..... Do you really need to write it, use it, and delete it once per iteration? I'm sure there are other ways to minimize the scope of the class, and if not, its fine to keep it at least within the scope of the try-block...

Comment: @AustinWBryan It is normal in Java (although usually, it would be anonymous, not named).  It is necessary because otherwise it can't reference `letter` from the surrounding scope. The class definition itself is only created once by the java compiler, so the only 'overhead' is from creating an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it

```
public class GUIThread {
    static Connection con; 
    static Statement stmt; 
    static ResultSet rs;
    int curRow = 0;

    public static void DoConnect(){
        try{
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Mariel";
            String uName = "mariel";
            String uPass = "1234";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String SQL = "SELECT * FROM LETTER";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            class printLetter extends TimerTask {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        rs.next();
                        final String letter;
                        letter = rs.getString("LETTER");
                        System.out.println(letter);
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        DoConnect();
                    }
                }
            }
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new printLetter(), 0, 2000);
        }
        catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        DoConnect();
    }
}
```